# Avoid bitmap scaling with different canvas size

Tags: android, android-canvas, scale, android-bitmap

I am trying to implement overlay transformation for Picasso library.
So, I am loading image into image view and want to display overlay using bitmpap

First of all I am fill canvas with transparent color
Then I am trying to draw drawable over

```
 @Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source){
    Bitmap workingBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(source);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap=workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
    Canvas canvas=new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

    canvas.drawColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_transparent));

    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled=false;
    Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_gif_white_24dp,options);

    canvas.drawBitmap(b,source.getWidth()/2,source.getHeight()/2,paint);
    source.recycle();
    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

The problem is that I see different overlay image size when canvas size is different. How I can avaid bitmap scaling depends on canvas size? I want to see same GIF size with different canvases size.

On first image canvas has w = 1280, h = 854, second image w = 480, h = 270

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found solution to scale bitmap depends on canvas size, it works well, but I wish to find out better solution

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_gif_white_24dp);
Bitmap drawableBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
double size = source.getWidth() * 0.15;
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(drawableBitmap, (int) size, (int) size, true);
```

Comment: the "better solution" is to use an `ImageView` which "rescales" your image filling the available space

Comment: You mean wrap imageView with Relative/Frame Layout and display overlay image above?

Comment: do you use some custom drawing / custom view?

Comment: Nope, it just image view.

Comment: so just use `setImageBitmap`, thats it, no `createScaledBitmap` at all

Comment: I am loading image into imageview, if I call setImageBitmap it will override original image, I just want to add overlay above original image.

Comment: then use a LayerDrawable

Comment: Using LayerDrawable I am getting same issue as described in post.

Comment: so use a custom `ImageView`, override its `onDraw` method and draw your overlay after calling `super.onDraw`